# how to translate typedef union to delphi?

Tags: c, delphi, header-files

1)

```
typedef union __rfun_gop_event_info
{
 unsigned int evt;
 struct
 {
  unsigned int reserved1:1;
  unsigned int reserved0:1;
  unsigned int f30:1;
  unsigned int f29:1;
 }frame;
}rfun_gop_event_info;
```

2)

```
typedef union __rfun_gop_event_info
{
 unsigned int evt;
 struct
 {
  unsigned int reserved1:1;
  unsigned int reserved0:1;
  unsigned int f30:1;
  unsigned int f29:1;
 }frame;
}rfun_gop_event_info;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please use the "code" feature to render your code samples.

Comment: check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282019/how-to-simulate-bit-fields-in-delphi-records

Comment: the obly hassle is - Object Pascal requires to put variant parts at the end of structure

Comment: Was it your intention to post the same block of code twice? Perhaps the second one was supposed to be different.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this article at Delphi Corner that explains **variant records** which is exactly what you need:

[DelphiCorner: Variant Records: The equivalent to the C-union structure](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/op6.htm)

Excerpt containing example:

```
type
 TPerson = record
   FirstName, LastName: string[40];
   BirthDate: TDate;
   case Citizen: Boolean of
     True: (BirthPlace: string[40]);
     False: (Country: string[20];
       EntryPort: string[20];
       EntryDate: TDate;
       ExitDate: TDate);
 end;
```

Comment: The bit fields are the real problem here