# C struct to Delphi record (conversion)

Tags: c, delphi

Can someone convert this C struct to delphi as in record?

```
typedef struct {
    Uint16    addr2:8;
    Uint16    addr1:8;
    Uint16    addr4:8;
    Uint16    addr3:8;
    Uint16    addr6:8;
    Uint16    addr5:8;
}MY_ADDR;
```

I tried it out myslef. But i couldn't figure out how to deal with **addr2:8** (:8) issue.

```
MY_ADDR = record
  addr2:8 : Uint16;
  addr1:8 : Uint16;
  addr4:8 : Uint16;
  addr3:8 : Uint16;
  addr6:8 : Uint16;
  addr5:8 : Uint16;
  end;
```

I am not sure i also need this or not?

```
pMY_ADDR = ^MY_ADDR;
```

Comment: Just curious, what does the 8 signify?  The width?  Been a long time since I wrote C...

Comment: They're bits. @SroMah, this may help: [bitfields] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282019/how-to-simulate-bit-fields-in-delphi-records)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MY_ADDR = record
  addr1 : Byte;
  addr2 : Byte;
  addr3 : Byte;
  addr4 : Byte;
  addr5 : Byte;
  addr6 : Byte;
end;
```

You need to swap them around due to byte ordering in MS C bitfields.